# ImportError: No module named Foundation

Tags: python, pyobjc

Hey all, I'm pretty new to python, so bear with me.

I want to write a simple script using some components of PyObjC. I'm running on Mac OS 10.5, so from what I've read, it's included.

However, opening up a simple python prompt and typing `import Foundation` gives me the error `ImportError: No module named Foundation`.

For reference, my sys.path is

```
['', '/var/hg/lib/python2.4/site-packages', '/Users/dmitri/lib/python', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.4/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PyObjC', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PyObjC', 
'/Users/dmitri', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python25.zip', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-darwin', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-mac', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-tk', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages']
```

`'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.4/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PyObjC',` and `'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PyObjC',` got in there because I was fooling around, but they don't seem to help me. The 2.4 version seems to exists but there, seems to be no folder with the aforementioned path in the 2.5 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it - for some reason, it was located under `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python`, so I had to just add that whole directory to my `$PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 0):

Where is the module `Foundation` located? Assuming it's in the same place as `PyObjC` -- `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/` -- then you have to add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/` to your `$PYTHONPATH` as well.

Comment: That is the problem though - there is no PyObjC in there - even though  from all the research I've done, PyObjC should be included with Mac OS 10.5.